# android https connection times out more frequently (self-signed certificate) than http connection does not

Tags: android, ssl

I have an app that uses a third-party server. Server supports both https/http requests.

For my app, I created a self-signed certificate to make an https connection to the  server. However, I **frequently** get "request timed out" with

`"SSL handshake timeout"` being dominant.

However, I switch over to HTTP connection, then timeouts are reduced considerably.

Has anyone experienced the same issue?

Is it ok to fallback to HTTP connection if HTTPS times out in PROD/Release environment for Android?

Code which makes connection

```
    String http_scheme = "http";
    int http_port = 80;
    String https_scheme = "https";
    int https_port = 443;
    ProtocolSocketFactory customFactory = new EasySslProtocolSocketFactory();
    Protocol lEasyHttps = new Protocol(https_scheme, customFactory, https_port);
    Protocol.registerProtocol(https_scheme, lEasyHttps);
    HostConfiguration hostConfig = new HostConfiguration();
    hostConfig.setHost(host, http_port, http_scheme);
    HttpConnectionManager connectionManager = new SimpleHttpConnectionManager();
    HttpConnectionManagerParams params = new HttpConnectionManagerParams();
    int maxHostConnections = 20;
    params.setMaxConnectionsPerHost(hostConfig, maxHostConnections);
    int connectTimeout = 30*1000;
    params.setConnectionTimeout(connectTimeout);
    params.setSoTimeout(connectTimeout);
    connectionManager.setParams(params);
```

Comment: Your server is using slow hardware or is overloaded.

Comment: @EJP..with m4.large....the timeouts for HTTPs did go down....thanks...so that takes care of slow hardware part....could you please provide some pointers on what is considered "overloaded"...for/in the context of this question only (in general, I know what "overloaded" mean)